# Difference between foreground-background system and realtime-operating system

Tags: operating-system, real-time, background-process, foreground, background-foreground

What would be the difference between these 2 types of systems. 
I could find definitions and characteristics for both, but I couldn't really find something that describes the exact difference in an understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

One could argue a long time over what a "real operating system" entails. In my mind, a fg-bg system is a very simple form of an operating system. It manages at least two tasks: the foreground task and the background task. If the foreground task is an interrupt handler, there may be a few different handlers, so it might actually be managing several tasks. An operating system's job, most basically, is to provide serviceable access to the computer's resources to the user in a flexible, programmable way, so that they can accomplish a desired function. There are more complex interrupt driven operating systems, time share systems, and hybrids of these.

Comment: Is there something connected with the Kernel in the difference between the two types of systems ?

Comment: Complex operating systems are designed in layers or levels. Sometimes viewed as concentric circles in operating system diagrams. The kernel is the innermost or lowest level, providing the drivers for hardware and all the fundamental functionality of the OS. Exactly much is at kernel level versus a higher application level is left up to the OS designer. If you have a lot of interest in the topic, check out a good solid book such as, "Operating Systems Design and Implementation" by Tannenbaum.